# Proof of the reflexivity of the accessibility relation

Tags: modal-logic

If accessibility is defined as follows:

> **Definition 1.** wRw' ↔ ∀<sub>p</sub> (w' ⊨ p → w ⊨ ◊p)

and the following axioms hold:

> **Axiom 1.** p → ◊p,
>
> **Axiom 2.** ∀<sub>p</sub>∀<sub>w</sub> (w ⊨ p → w ⊨ ◊p),

are the following claims true?

> **Claim 1.** ∀<sub>w</sub> (w ⊨ p → w ⊨ ◊p) (by Axiom 1 and Definition 1),
>
> **Claim 2.** ∀<sub>w</sub> (wRw) (by Axiom 2 and Claim 1).

Answer (score 1):

The task is to prove the correspondence between the so-called T axiom (φ → ♢φ) and the reflexivity of the accessibility relation. To do so we must be very explicit about the following important distinction:

> **Definition 1a.** (*Frame*) A *frame* F = (W, R) is a directed graph.
>
> **Definition 1b.** (*Model*) A *model* M = (F, V) is a labelled directed graph.

Directed graphs are simply a bunch of connected points (in this context, the points are called 'worlds', the connections form the 'accessibility relation'). *Labelled* directed graphs are directed graphs but with each point having a label that tells us which propositions are true at that point. We want to show that:

> **Fact 2.** Formula (φ → ♢φ) is valid  iff R is reflexive.

It turns out, however, that "[t]ruth in models is not appropriate for bringing out such correspondences" between formulas and properties of the accessibility relation, "as special valuations [in our terminology: labelings] may validate axioms even though the underlying frame has no nice behavior at all" (van Benthem 2010, p. 101). So what we really want to show is that:

> **Fact 2.** Formula (φ → ♢φ) is valid  on frame F = (W, R) iff R is reflexive.

The definition of frame validity is simple to formulate:

> **Definition 3.** (*Frame Validity*) Formula φ is valid on a frame F = (W, R) iff for all models M = (F, V) based on that frame and worlds w ∈ W, we have (M, w) |= φ.

The "for all models" is the key. Let's now tackle the task by splitting it into its two directions:

> **Fact 2a.** (*Only if direction*) Formula (φ → ♢φ) is valid  on frame F = (W, R) only if R is reflexive.

*Proof.* We prove by contraposition. Assume that F = (W, R) is *not* reflexive, with the goal of showing that (φ → ♢φ) is not valid on F. To show that (φ → ♢φ) is not valid on F it will suffice to present a counter-model M = (F, V) based on F where for some w ∈ W, (M, w) |= φ ∧ ¬♢φ. Consider M = (W, R, V), where W = {w}, R is irreflexive and V(p) = W. Informally, we have a single node called 'w' with the label 'p' meaning that proposition p is true at world w; we have no other worlds. Now, since p is true at w, we have (M, w) |= p. But since there are no other worlds and (by irreflexivity of R) w cannot access itself, (M, w) |= ♢p is false. That means that we have a pointed world (M, w) s.t. (M, w) |= p ∧ ¬♢p. That means that (φ → ♢φ) cannot be valid on frame F.                                                                                 ■

> **Fact 2b.** (*If direction*) Formula (φ → ♢φ) is valid  on frame F = (W, R) if R is reflexive.

*Proof.* We assume that R is reflexive, with the goal of showing that (φ → ♢φ) is valid on reflexive frames. Let M = (F, V) be any model based on such a frame. For an arbitrary point w ∈ W, we want to show that (M, w) |= φ → ♢φ. Suppose, for contradiction, that (M, w) |= φ → ♢φ is false. That will be the case iff (M, w) |= φ and (M, w) |= ¬♢φ are both true. By the box-diamond duality, this second conjunct is true just in case (M, w) |= ▢¬φ is true. But by the first conjunct, world w satisfies φ and since R is reflexive, it means that w sees a world (namely itself) that satisfies φ, so (M, w) |= ▢¬φ cannot be true. Since the assumption that (M, w) |= φ → ♢φ is false led to a contradiction, we know that (M, w) |= φ → ♢φ is true. Since (M, w) was arbitrary, we know that (φ → ♢φ) is valid on reflexive frames.                ■

Those two facts allow us to justify the desired claim, namely that:

> **Fact 2.** Formula (φ → ♢φ) is valid  on frame F = (W, R) iff R is reflexive.

*Proof.* Combine proofs of Fact (2a) and (2b).                                                                                          ■

**References**

van Benthem, J. (2010) [*Modal Logic for Open Minds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157586598X), Stanford, CSLI Lecture Notes #199; §9.1.
Holliday, W.H. (2012) [*Modal Reasoning*](http://philosophy.berkeley.edu/people/page/123), Lecture Course (Spring), UC Berkeley; Lecture 5.
Pacuit, E. (2009) ["Notes on Modal Logic"](http://web.pacuit.org/classes/logicai-cmu/ml-notes.pdf); §3.1.

Comment: On Fact 2a. you say "R is reflexive and V(p) = W" V(p) = W means p is true in/at W, correct? Sorry if that sound naïve, i'm still a beginner in (modal) logic.

Comment: @user8083 Exactly (since W = {w}, V(p) = W = {w}, i.e. p is true at w).

Comment: @user8083 I hope after looking at the answer to your other question this now makes sense. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What good introductory textbook(s) on modal logic would you recommend? I've tried using Modal Logic for Open Minds, but it was too technical.

Comment: @user8083 Hughes and Cresswell I hear is pretty accessible. Van Benthem has an earlier book on modal logic that's a little more accessible. Take a look at Pacuit's Notes I listed in the references section. John MacFarlane has excellent introductory notes on his website. I'll think more about this and comment when I have better suggestions.

Comment: Okay, so let me see if i understand this. On fact 2a, since there are no other worlds other than w, and R is irreflexive, that means that ¬♢p is true at w, right? So whenever we have a world w that does not access any other worlds, including itself, this implies that any proposition p true at w is ¬♢p? And what does it mean to say that a frame is reflexive? does it mean that all worlds (∀w(wRw)) in the frame access themselves or that some worlds (∃w(wRw)) access themselves?

Comment: All of that is correct. To say that a frame is reflexive is to say that _all_ points have loops to themselves. Irreflexive frames have _no_ such loops. Frames that are neither reflexive nor irreflexive (this may seen strange at first) have at least two worlds w, v s.t. wRw and ~vRv.

Comment: I'm about to ask a question on the math stack exchange (since im not sure it would be appropriate to post it here) about a 'proof' that i (think) discovered. So my question is, if we have a frame that consists of two worlds w1 and w2, and the only relation is w1Rw2, and since w2⊨□⊥, w1⊨◊T and □□⊥, right?

Comment: @user8083 That's right. w2 |= □□⊥, since it sees no other worlds, any sentence of form □--- will be satisfied at w2.

Comment: Yes, but does w1⊨□□⊥∧◊⊤?

Comment: @user8083 Depends on the reflexivity of R. Is the R reflexive? In other words, does w1 see itself?

Comment: No, R={(w1,w2)}

Comment: @user8083 Oops, sorry. Yes. Since w1 sees a world, w1 |= ◊⊤, and since all worlds w1 sees (viz. w2) see no world, w1 |= □□⊥.

Comment: @user8083 Hey. I noticed your recent post is gone from math.se. I don't know what happened there. I hope it's not because of my critical comments. I was quite satisfied with your response, so I waited until you saw my reply to you and then deleted my post. Sorry if it was because of my comments. Perhaps you can share with me what exactly you're trying to prove and we'll figure out how to prove it together. If you'd like to discuss before posting, just shoot me an email to hunan131 (at gmail.com).

Comment: I deleted it because i wasnt sure it made sense, but i'll post it again. The basic idea is to find the modal depth of '⊥' at some world in a frame where: 1. R is irreflexive 2. There is exactly one world w that is not accessed by any worlds, and which accesses only one world 3. There is exactly one world w that does not access any worlds, and w is accessed by only one world. In your deleted response you said that you couldnt make sense of the idea of modal depth at a particular world, since modal depth is a purely syntactic concept, so im not sure my idea makes sense.

Comment: @user8083 I see. As regards my claim about depth being syntactical, let me elaborate a little. Consider the formula \Box^i\bot, for some positive i. This formula is true and false at various worlds, depending on what they can and cannot see. But the modal depth of this formula is a function purely of the number of iterations of the \Box, which is equal simply to i.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong in the consequent of the formula. It's supposed to be  ∀wk |= box^(n-k)+1

Comment: @user8083 I think I see what your original claim was now. Take an arbitrary world w_k. The index k of that world is used in the formula (n-k)+1 to determine the number of 'jumps' required to reach a dead-end. Something like that. Does that sound about right?

Comment: That sounds right. But remember that what were trying to find is the amount of 'boxes' in front of ⊥. We already know that wn, being a dead end , satisfies box⊥, so wn-1 satisfies boxbox⊥. The number of boxes increases by one as we go one 'step' backwards from wn to w1. See how this resembles an arithmetic sequence. So the question is: "how many boxes are in front of ⊥ at wk?"

Comment: @user8083 I do. Excellent.